# Asciidoctor nested table

Tags: asciidoctor, asciidoctor-pdf

I am trying to create nested tables in my Asciidoctor pdf output but I cannot find the syntax.

If I understand it right, nested tables should be supported in Asciidoctor as of 1.5.0. I am running a Docker container that has 1.5.5 (https://github.com/asciidoctor/docker-asciidoctor).

I've tried as per example in table 11 here: http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/newtables.html but to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Note that Asciidoc and Asciidoctor are [not the same thing](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/asciidoc-asciidoctor-diffs/).
Therefore, make sure you are looking at the [correct documentation](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/).

I have not tried it, but if a nested table is going to work, the cell containing it will have to use the asciidoc [style](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#cols-style). You will then most likely have put the table in a [block](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#literal-text-and-blocks) and escape all the pipe symbols (using \| instead of | or using some other delimiter).

A web search turned up [this open issue](https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/413) in the AsciiDoctor tracker requesting (improvements to) nested table support. So this seems not to be implemented yet at least in some backends. The first comment contains an example of how to specify a nested table.

Are you sure you cannot use something other than nested tables? They are usually not the most readable thing.

Comment: Hi jackrabbit, Thank you for your response! I know they aren't the same thing. I found https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/6 which claims to be solving the nested table, but I cannot figure out how. 

My real need is to have a large number of small but differently sized tables in three rows on one page for a "cheat sheet" layout. This guy https://github.com/asciidoctor/asciidoctor-pdf/issues/327 seems to have the same need but I read the answer as though it is not possible.

I tried escaping the pipe as you suggested but that just puts the text in as plain text.

Comment: That issue talks about general asciidoc content, mostly geared towards lists. Tables evidently doesn't work, as shown in the issue I linked to (413). I would look at the problem differently: make each column a separate "page" and then configure the output plugin to put 3 "pages" onto 1 target page. Sort of like making a multi-column output format and introducing column breaks.

Comment: Hi jackrabbit, In theory I understand what you mean but I am too new to this to figure out how to do it. Could you elaborate on your last sentence? Thank you so much for taking time to answer me, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Not knowing what your target format is makes it difficult to answer. I expect you want to use the docbook backend and to post-process the result into PDF. The FO transformation apparently supports setting the number of columns on a page: http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/PrintOutput.html#TwoColumn You just need to figure out how to force a column break then.

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, you need to delete two unintended newlines. Here's the modified content.

```
[width="75%",cols="1,2a"]
|==============================================
|Normal cell  |Cell with nested table

[cols="2,1"]
!==============================================
!Nested table cell 1 !Nested table cell 2
!==============================================

|==============================================
```

I must say I used `asciidoctor-pdf` first time and although the process has been streamlined as much as possible with the docker image, there is a much quicker way to get rendered feedback: Asciidoctor.js - a Chrome extension that converts your .adoc file to HTML and reloads when you save the file.

Asciidoctor.js comes from the same great team that created and maintain Asciidoctor, so it has latest Asciidoctor under the hood.